# Работа одноврменно с двумя ветками

Tags: git, git-branch

В связи с устранением ошибки в проекте, было принято решение сделать крупномасштабный рефакторинг в отдельном Git Branch.

Необходимо теперь сравнить поведение старой и новой версий.

К сожалению подходящих средств работы одновременно с двумя бранчами не нашел.

Пришлось выполнить `checkout` в новую папку проекта с оригинальной веткой.

Существует ли лучший способ?

Использую `Visual Studio 2010` с плагином `Git Source Control Provider`

Comment: Что значит "сравнить поведение"? Вы хотите прогнать тесты на каждой ветке? Или Вы хотите сравнить содержимое файлов?

Comment: сравнить поведение программы

Comment: У меня нет тестов - это GUI приложение, а не библиотека

Comment: Условно говоря, Вы хотите прогнать руками две сборки Вашей программы? Дебаггером будете пользоваться? Я просто пытаюсь понять, стоит ли сейчас заморачиваться с решением, или можно просто переключиться между ветками и дважды собрать проект. Да, кстати, насколько он крупный?

Comment: Да, но даже если нужно будет отлаживать только одну ветку, то результат компиляции другой ветки я должен сохранить для запуска. Проект не очень крупный. С сабжом сталкиваюсь впервые, поэтому поставленный вопрос может звучать глупо.

Comment: *С сабжом сталкиваюсь впервые* — вероятно, до этого был опыт с *subversion*? там «ветка» — как раз и есть отдельный каталог с исходниками (насколько помню). в *git* же «ветка» — это не каталог и даже не набор коммитов, а всего лишь **указатель** на коммит. и даже каталога с исходниками может не быть вовсе (т.н. `bare`-репозиторий).

Comment: Я бы подумал в сторону автоматической интеграции. Пишем скрипт, который переключает ревизии, например по тегам, и прогоняет тесты на них. А программист в это время кофе пьёт.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Две копии локального репозитория - лучший вариант для работы сразу с двумя ветками.